# Inserir dados no banco quando dado ok em alert

Tags: php, javascript

Tenho uma coluna no *phpmyadmin* chamada msg que recebe valores inteiros `1` ou `0`.

Quando `1`, ao usuário entrar no site será exibido um `alert('Seja bem vindo!');` como fazer para que quando o usuário clicar em OK seja atualizado msg para `0`?

Comment: Já tens algum código que comunica com a base de dados?

Comment: Acho mais interessante você usar o ```window.confirm``` do Javascript. Se tiver dúvida quanto a sintaxe você posta aqui. Eu acredito que você já tenha a rotina para persistir os dados no banco, logo você só quer melhorar o nível de interatividade do sistema, certo?